# Hyperledger cannot update channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to update an existing channel to enable lifecyle.

**Official link:**
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/enable_cc_lifecycle.html

**Launching this command on my peer:**

```
peer channel update -f config_update_in_envelope.pb -c channelid -o orderer.domain.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/s
rc/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/*******/ca
```

**Error**

```
got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- initializing channelconfig failed: could 
not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP 
managerfailed: expected at least one CA certificate
```

I tried all existing ca certs available on my network and It's not working,

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error was "probably" due to a version mismatch ... one orderer used on my network was still using an 1.4 version, since this orderer has been upgraded it's not possible to reproduce this error again. Even if I do not understand why the error msg is talking about a CA file ...